# How to set OrderedView of the list view programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, listview, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I am trying to modify the List View of Link list in SharePoint 2010. What I need to do is to allow/disallow users to order item of Link list programmatically. We can do this easily using SharePoint browser.

How to do this using SharePoint UI.
Goto List->Modify Views.
There is "Sort" option "Allow users to order items in this view? ".

But I need to do this programmatically and the accessor "SPView.OrderedView" is read only so I am struck.

I can however change the sorting columns using CAML.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Prakash Tandukar

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar thread of MSDN Forums - [Ordering View Programmatically](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/sharepoint2010programming/thread/0ddca0f6-2b17-4f4a-9d66-f3d684ed4a11). Hope this helps.